# Combining SQL query Array in PHP based on element

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have made a favorites function on my site that someone can choose different items that go together and save it as a favorite package in their account. All items are saved in a favorite table with a favorite ID number. Anything that has the same ID number go together. This will save under the customer that is logged in.

I am trying to import this array into a PHP page and display the items graphicly in a lightbox type look, but have been running into a lot of trouble combining them together to display them properly.

The array and php code are below. The array is generated from a SQL query. The items of array [0] and [1] need to be combined together in such a way that I can show the images from each one together (the images actually go on top of each other to make it look like a package.

Here is a link to the page so you get an idea: https://www.viva-cards.com/products/package-designer you will not be able to see the favorite function unless you log-in though

I basically need to combine the same fav_seq ids together, but still be able to differentiate itm_id, offer_id, inv_type_id, , inv_thumbnail_url and offer_description, as they have different images and such that go with them. I have been hitting my head to a brick wall on this. Is there a way to do this on the php page, or do I have to do it at the SQL query stage? What am I doing wrong?

The following is the code of the array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 6
        [itm_id] => 81
        [fav_seq] => 1
        [offer_id] => 1
        [inv_css_tag] => 
        [inv_type_id] => TYPE1
        [inv_thumbnail_url] => image1-thumb.png
        [offer_description] => Offer1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 6
        [itm_id] => 198
        [fav_seq] => 1
        [offer_id] => 1
        [inv_css_tag] => csstag
        [inv_type_id] => TYPE2
        [inv_thumbnail_url] => image2-thumb.jpg
        [offer_description] => Offer2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 6
        [itm_id] => 810
        [fav_seq] => 2
        [offer_id] => 4
        [inv_css_tag] => 
        [inv_type_id] => TYPE1
        [inv_thumbnail_url] => image3-thumb.png
        [offer_description] => Offer4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 6
        [itm_id] => 98
        [fav_seq] => 2
        [offer_id] => 4
        [inv_css_tag] => csstag
        [inv_type_id] => TYPE2
        [inv_thumbnail_url] => image4-thumb.jpg
        [offer_description] => Offer4
    )
```

This is the code I am using on the php page to generate the display:

```
<div>
    <h2>Favorites Saved</h2>

    <?php 
    foreach($this->favorite_seq as $favorites){
        if(empty($favorites['fav_seq'])){ 
     // Nothing
    ?>
<?php }else {?>                 
        <div id="favoritesThumbnailWrapper"> <!-- For TYPE1 -->
     <div id="favoritesReferralThumb" class="cardPositionMiddle1">
         <img src="<?= $this->inventory_url . $favorites['inv_thumbnail_url'];?>">
     </div>

     <div id="favoritesPresentationThumb"> <!-- For TYPE2 -->
         <img src="<?= $this->inventory_url . $favorites['inv_thumbnail_url'];?>">
     </div>

     <div id="favoritesOffer"> <!-- For OFFER DESCRIPTION -->
         <span><?= $favorites['offer_description'];?></span>
     </div>

</div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
$favArray = array();
foreach($this->favorite_seq as $favorites){
    if(!empty($favorites['fav_seq'])){
        $favArray[$favorites['fav_seq']][] = $favorites;
    }
}
print_r($favArray);
```

Itterate on `$favArray` to display records then.